# MySQL dynamically display distinct values from a column with count of occurrences?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Using MySQL 5.5.34 on MAMP.

How do I display distinct values with count of occurrences ?

`my_table` looks like this:

```
id fruit
01 apple
02 orange
03 grape
04 apple
05 banana
06 orange
```

What i'm trying to display is something like:

```
apple 2
banana 1
grape 1
orange 2
fruits 6
```

I could hard code the values and use count with distinct but I'm sure there is a dynamic way. I've found some examples on here using `group by` and `with rollup`, but I can't seem to get the syntax right or find a example.

The non-dynamic way I'm doing right now:

```
SELECT fruit,COUNT(*) as count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY fruit
ORDER BY fruit ASC
WITH ROLLUP;
```

I hope somebody has some a clear example. I've been trying for many hours now. thanks!

Comment: just eliminate the rollup. it's pointless for a single-group query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the rollup row say `fruits` instead of `NULL` using the [**IFNULL()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function

You also don't need `ORDER BY`

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
SELECT IFNULL(fruit,'fruits') fruit,COUNT(*) as count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY fruit
WITH ROLLUP;
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
mysql> drop database if exists fruitdb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database fruitdb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use fruitdb
Database changed
mysql> create table my_table
    -> (id int not null auto_increment,
    -> fruit varchar(20) not null,
    -> primary key (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into my_table (fruit) values
    -> ('apple'),('orange'),('grape'),
    -> ('apple'),('banana'),('orange');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from my_table;
+----+--------+
| id | fruit  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | apple  |
|  2 | orange |
|  3 | grape  |
|  4 | apple  |
|  5 | banana |
|  6 | orange |
+----+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(fruit,'fruits') fruit,COUNT(*) as count
    -> FROM my_table
    -> GROUP BY fruit
    -> WITH ROLLUP;
+--------+-------+
| fruit  | count |
+--------+-------+
| apple  |     2 |
| banana |     1 |
| grape  |     1 |
| orange |     2 |
| fruits |     6 |
+--------+-------+
5 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: this works perfectly! thanks Rolando, you have saved my sanity. (and thanks for clearing up my poorly-phrased question).